# bash проверить наличие элемента массива в строке

Tags: bash

Есть массив с исключениями

```
EXCLUDE_LIST=(
    "программа"
    "сканер"
    "компьютер"
)
```

и строка

`str="Программа для просмотра изображений и факсов"`

Как можно проверить наличие какого либо элемента массива в строке `str`? Если в строке `str` встречается какой-либо элемент массива, то, например, не выводить эту строку на экран.

`str="Программа для просмотра изображений и факсов"` - Не выводить на экран

`str="Приложение для просмотра изображений и факсов"` - Выводить на экран

Проверить наличие строки в массиве можно легко:

```
if [[ " ${array[@]} " =~ " ${value} " ]]; then
    echo "Есть такая строка в массиве"
fi
```

**Но как сделать наоборот?**

Comment: `if [[ ! " ${array[@]} " =~ " ${value} " ]];`

Comment: Не подходит. Вы проверяете "если  вхождение строки в каком-либо элементе массива является ложью". А нужно наоборот. Проверить вхождение элемента массива в строке

Comment: `str="Программа для просмотра изображений и факсов" - Не выводить на экран` — а по какому критерию «не выводить»? изложенному в вопросе критерию строка не удовлетворяет: в ней нет ни одной из указанных вами строк (строки `Программа` и `программа` — это **разные** строки, можете проверить).

Comment: Четко ясно прописано в вопросе по какому критерию. По критерию присутствия или отсутствия строки, подстроки в элементе массива. (проверка условия должно быть регистронезависимым)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте ! перед условием if:

```
if ! [[ ${ARRAY[@]} =~ $VALUE ]]; then
    echo "Есть такая строка в массиве"
fi
```